# Permissions: System Volume Information folder, Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, permissions

How can I directly access files in the System Volume Information folder while booted into Windows?

I have tried to change the file permissions by right clicking on the folder and selecting properties, then the Security tab, but no matter what I try it will not allow changing the owner or adding a user with read permissions. I always get Access Denied error message.

Is there a command line command that will do it, or other method while booted into Windows?

Comment: You might check here on the accepted answer to see if this is what does it. I don't have Windows 7 around to test right now myself... http://superuser.com/questions/645207/accidentally-moved-folder-to-system-volume-information

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the command prompt:

(hit enter key after each command)

> ICACLS "C:\system volume information" /grant YourLoginID:F

this gives permissions to the folder

(yourLoginID= the account name you wish to grant permissions to)

> ICACLS "C:\system volume information" /grant YourLoginID:F /T

this gives permissions to the folder contents.

Now you can view files in the System Volume Information folder.

**To undo this:**

> ICACLS "C:\system volume information" /remove YourLoginID /T

Removes access to everything in the folder.

then

> ICACLS "C:\System Volume Information" /remove yourLoginID

Removes access to the specified folder itself.

[Source](http://www.sevenforums.com/performance-maintenance/222588-how-delete-system-volume-information-folder-win-7-a-3.html)

Note: On my system when I ran the second command it failed to set permissions on one restore point file {xxxxxx}, maybe it is in use by the system and cannot be changed, not sure. I can see it in the SVI folder though, strange.

Also, using the Remove commands listed did not revert the changes, I can still view the files. I should have set a restore point before trying this, eek!

Comment: Thanks so much Moab recovered 10GB back after using an Acronis True Image 2018 trial. As additional info for me running Windows 10 I had to run the delete command after the first two as: DEL /f "C:\System Volume Information\FileProtector\................." (Windows Explorer just ignored delete requests when navigated to)

Answer (score 0):

You may find that running the icacls command you receive an error saying access is denied.

You could try running a TAKEOWN command

/F specifies the (local) folder for which you want to change ownership.
/R is for Recursive (includes subfolders...)
/A is to give Ownership to the Local Administrators group (otherwise it would give Ownership to the currently logged on user).

Once Ownership has been changed, you (as a member of the Local Administrators Group) now have access to these files.

Depending on the size of the directory, this can take a good long while to run.