# Large amount of space on C drive (system volume information folder) used by files with .BLOB extension in Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, disk-cleanup

I need clean up my C drive. I found `system volume information` folder size is 66 GB. That contains many folders and files with **BLOB** extension in this path:
`C:\system volume information\FileProtector\FileStorage\`

How I can delete these files?
Is safe to remove?
I install many software especially visual studio 2017.
Here my Screenshots:
[image]
[image]

Comment: Did you try with Windows Disk Cleanup to manage that junks? Or with CCleaner?

Comment: Yes, `Windows Disk Cleanup` not detect those files. Show total 500 Mb for clean. Same for CCleaner too.

Comment: You can always just delete everything in System Volume information.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sounds like you have [Acronis True Image](https://kb.acronis.com/content/59356) running on your PC. This utility is intended to protect you from ransomware by giving you the chance to stop third party applications changing your files, and uses up to ~20% of your C: drive to maintain controlled backups of files.

[A user describes similar issues](https://forum.acronis.com/forum/acronis-true-image-2017-forum/hundreds-thousands-contentfileblob-files-devouring-disk-space) to yours on the Acronis forums:

> After tedious searching, I found out that these files are being
>   generated by Acronis Active Protection. The path to these files begins
>   with C:\System Volume Information\FileProtector\FileStorage and within
>   that directory are subfolders containing thousands of subfolders, each
>   containing thousands more, each containing ONE file called
>   "ContentFile.BLOB."

So that's where the files are coming from. You can't simply delete them because the Acronis service is stopping you in the same way it would stop ransomware. To remove them, you'd have to stop the Acronis Active Protection service, and remove the files as administrator. That would probably cause issues with your Acronis utility, so I'm not sure it's necessarily a good idea.

Another Acronis forum thread (in German) was started by another user with essentially the same issue as you.

In both threads, the 'Forum Heroes' and Acronis employees indicate that **a very large size of the FileProtector folder is not normal, and that the user should open a ticket with Acronis Support**.

Assuming you have an Acronis account already, it looks like you can do this at: `http://account.acronis.com/auth/login`

If you don't yet have an account, you could create one (and register your software) by following the steps on the Acronis Knowledge Base: `http://kb.acronis.com/regacc`

I don't yet have enough reputation to post all the links I wanted to in this Answer. Sorry about that.

Comment: Thanks a lot @FosseWay for your answer. I uninstall `Acronis True Image`. But for access `System Volume Information` i use this answer: https://superuser.com/questions/1041341/permissions-system-volume-information-folder-windows-7  Now I move files to another drive. :)