# How to grant Total Access and Special Permission to my user in C: and D: drive on Windows 11?

Tags: windows, command-line, powershell, permissions, windows-11

I'm having a tough time trying to set Total Control and Special Permission to my User using the terminal on Windows 11.

How can i grant total control for my user? And by total control i really mean total control and special permission to do anything i want, like delete any folder i want or file i want in the system?

Even access, or modify the "System Volume Information" folder, for example.

Comment: Being an Administrator provides total control of any file you create or download. What directory is the file or folder in that your unable to delete?

Comment: Assuming you know better than the system designers is what got us massively insecure systems and malware infections. If you absolutely need access to these areas then you can probably do it with [using this method](https://superuser.com/questions/1041341/permissions-system-volume-information-folder-windows-7/1041350#1041350) but you can break a lot of things very easily and get to a point where all you can do is wipe and reinstall your system. Let the system do its job, this is the equivalent of "I went into the Windows directory and tidied everything up and now my system doesn't boot..."

Comment: just add any user to administrator group. then you dont need to think about the permissions. but however i think this question is plenty off topic

Comment: I think you lack clarity as to why you would want to use this. I think this could be an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) personally. Further information and what you have tried so far would also help further assist.

Answer (score 3):

This is a **bad idea** for many many reasons, including breaking your system in a way that couldn't be restored.

That being said, you can enter "explorer.exe" in the search bar of the start menu, right click on the result given and click "Run as Administrator".

That should give you admin access to all files and folders within the window that'll open.

Once again: **Very bad idea**