# Main Desktop folder has accidentally been set to Local Drive D

Tags: hard-drive, desktop

I accidentally set my Desktop folder to Local Drive D.

Now, I cannot switch back to the desktop folder in C:/Users/hp since to do that I will also have to move the "System Volume Information" folder of Local Disk D, which is not possible.

Can I somehow revert my desktop back to its original location?

FYI, here are the screenshots of the steps and errors:

Step 1:
[image]

Step 2:
[image]

Step 3 (Error):
[image]

I am at a loss regarding how to solve this problem. This also means that I cannot replace my HDD since my Desktop folder is apparently stuck on Local Disk D forever.

Even though this might not be that huge of an issue currently to me, it might be in the future, so I want to find a way to solve it now.

Comment: I presume you get the same error if you select "Restore Default"? [This](https://superuser.com/questions/645207/) should be applicable.  If it isn't you should [edit] your question with enough details to determine the reason that System Volume Information folder is in that location to begin with. One thing that might help is disabling the synchronization of the Desktop folder to OneDrive. Since it does not appear you moved the entire user's profile, in theory, you should be able to edit the registry location of the desktop to a different location manually.

Comment: @Ramhound thanks! I'll check if it works and update my answer.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest the following :

- Ensure that the folder `%USERPROFILE%\Desktop` still exists, and check
  if it is empty
- Run `regedit`
- Position to the key
  `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\User Shell Folders`
- Set the item `Desktop` to the value of `%USERPROFILE%\Desktop`
- If the folder `%USERPROFILE%\Desktop` is empty,
  *copy* the *contents* of `D:\Desktop` to `%USERPROFILE%\Desktop`
- Log out and in, or reboot Windows
- If everything is OK, delete folder `D:\Desktop`.